# C# Receiving values from a list

Tags: c#

I am retrieving a set of values from a List. My problem is there are repetitions of the items that I am retrieving. i.e, I am getting the value of the same item more than once.

Here is the code.

```
            string test = ""; ;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand("select * from Color_Subjects", con);
            SqlDataReader read = get.ExecuteReader();

            List<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>(); // Declare a list of subjects
            while (read.Read())
            {
                subjects.Add(new Subject()
                {
                    SubjectName = read.GetString(0),
                    Color = ((int)read.GetValue(1))
                });

                //Get All Unique Colors
                List<int> allColors = subjects.Select(x => x.Color).Distinct().ToList();

                //Iterate through each color and get subjects associated with that color

                foreach (int thisColor in allColors)
                {
                    List<Subject> subjectsForThisColor = subjects.Where(x => x.Color == thisColor).ToList();
                    // Output to console -- 
                    foreach (Subject s in subjectsForThisColor)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(s.SubjectName + " - " + s.Color);
                        test += s.SubjectName + " -" + s.Color + "\n";
                    }
                }

            }
            TextBox7.Text = test;
```

Observed output :

```
C#   -1
C#   -1
SSM  -2
C#   -1
SSM  -2
OOMD     -3
C#   -1
SSM  -2
OOMD     -3
MMT  -4
C#   -1
SSM  -2
OOMD     -3
MMT  -4
Elective-1   -5
C#   -1
SSM  -2
OOMD     -3
MMT  -4
Elective-1   -5
Elective-2   -6
C#   -1
SSM  -2
OOMD     -3
MMT  -4
Elective-1   -5
Elective-2   -6
Elective-3   -7
C#   -1
SSM  -2
OOMD     -3
MMT  -4
Elective-1   -5
Elective-2   -6
Elective-3   -7
Elective-4   -8
C#   -1
SSM  -2
OOMD     -3
MMT  -4
Elective-1   -5
Elective-2   -6
Elective-5   -6
Elective-3   -7
Elective-4   -8
C#   -1
SSM  -2
OOMD     -3
MMT  -4
Elective-1   -5
Elective-2   -6
Elective-5   -6
Elective-3   -7
Elective-4   -8
Elective-6   -8
```

Required Output :

```
    C#           -1
    SSM          -2
    OOMD         -3
    MMT          -4
    Elective-1   -5
    Elective-2   -6
    Elective-5   -6
    Elective-3   -7
    Elective-4   -8
    Elective-6   -8
```

Comment: Why is `//Get All Unique Colors` and everything after it *inside* the `while` loop? -- try put it outside after the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is code is performing `Distinct`and rest printing logic on each read, which is not you want.

Move your logic outside looping.

```
while (read.Read()) 
{
    subjects.Add(new Subject() 
    {
        SubjectName = read.GetString(0),
        Color = ((int) read.GetValue(1))
    });
}

//Get All Unique Colors
List < int > allColors = subjects.Select(x => x.Color).Distinct().ToList();

//Iterate through each color and get subjects associated with that color

foreach(int thisColor in allColors) 
{
    List < Subject > subjectsForThisColor = subjects.Where(x => x.Color == thisColor).ToList();
    // Output to console -- 
    foreach(Subject s in subjectsForThisColor) 
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(s.SubjectName + " - " + s.Color);
        test += s.SubjectName + " -" + s.Color + "\n";
    }
}
```

In addition, if you are looking for formatting your output, try exploring [`Composite Formatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) options and do something like.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,-10}-{1}", s.SubjectName,s.Color);
```

Answer (score 1):

how about replacing

```
SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand("select * from Color_Subjects", con);
```

with

```
SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT * from Color_Subjects", con);
```

to determine duplicates database side

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<Subject> subjectsForThisColor = subjects.Where(x => x.Color == thisColor).Select(c=>c).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the logic a little.. Try this...

```
        string test = ""; ;
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand("select * from Color_Subjects", con);
        SqlDataReader read = get.ExecuteReader();

        List<Subject> subjects = new List<Subject>(); // Declare a list of subjects
        while (read.Read())
        {
            subjects.Add(new Subject()
            {
                SubjectName = read.GetString(0),
                Color = ((int)read.GetValue(1))
            });
        }
            //Get All Unique Colors
        List<int> allColors = subjects.Select(x => x.Color).Distinct().ToList();

        //Iterate through each color and get subjects associated with that color

        foreach (int thisColor in allColors)
        {
            List<Subject> subjectsForThisColor = subjects.Where(x => x.Color == thisColor).ToList();
            // Output to console -- 
            foreach (Subject s in subjectsForThisColor)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(s.SubjectName + " - " + s.Color);
                test += s.SubjectName + " -" + s.Color + "\n";
            }
        }

        TextBox7.Text = test;
```